# Route traffic between autoscale group and cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-run

I have an autoscale group backend  service under http loadbalancing.
I'm moving this service to cloud run. Now I want to set up weight-based load balancing between these two, with 95% of traffic going to the autoscale group and 5% going to the cloud run.

Tried mutiple things but no luck, also didnt find any official document for the same.

route traffic between autoscale group and cloud run
no option to use different types of endpoints in http load balancer

```
defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXXXXXXXXX/global/backendServices/backend-instancegroup-bs
fingerprint: Z2O8KiXXOIGDU=XXXXX
hostRules:
- hosts:
  - test.com
  pathMatcher: path-matcher-1
- hosts:
  - '*.test.com'
  pathMatcher: path-matcher-2
kind: compute#urlMap
name: backend-dev-external-lb2
pathMatchers:
- defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXXXXXXXXX/global/backendBuckets/backend-bucket-bs
  name: path-matcher-1
  pathRules:
  - paths:
    - /login
    - /healthcheck
    routeAction:
      weightedBackendServices:
      - backendService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXXXXXXXXX/global/backendServices/backend-instancegroup-bs
        weight: 95
      - backendService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXXXXXXXXX/global/backendServices/backend-cloudrun-bs
        weight: 5
- defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXXXXXXXXX/global/backendBuckets/backend-bucket-bs
  name: path-matcher-2
  pathRules:
  - paths:
    - /login
    - /healthcheck
    routeAction:
      weightedBackendServices:
      - backendService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXXXXXXXXX/global/backendServices/backend-instancegroup-bs
        weight: 95
      - backendService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXXXXXXXXX/global/backendServices/backend-cloudrun-bs
        weight: 5
```

Comment: Did you try with a load balancer? https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-global-traffic-mgmt#split_traffic_between_two_services

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, yes I tried with the above-mentioned config I am getting the below error

`
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.url-maps.import) HTTPError 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.defaultService': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXXXX/global/backendServices/backend-instancegroup-bs'. Advanced routing rules are not supported for scheme EXTERNAL
`

Answer (score 1):

I am able to achieve this.

so the backends which I am using are created via GCP UI which has default --load-balancing-scheme=EXTERNAL

but in order to use the advanced routing methods mentioned the google doc requires load-balancing-scheme=EXTERNAL_MANAGED.

after creating new backends with `load-balancing-scheme=EXTERNAL_MANAGED` it's working

Also, you have to create `gcloud compute forwarding-rules` with the same `load-balancing-scheme`

This means you have to create all components in load balancer  manually